# List of Radiobuttons

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

Excuse my question it is extreme simple or even silly but its been bothering me for the last hour and I can't get it going.

I have defined a list of of RadiButtons and a have added 4 `radiobuttons`:

```
 List<RadioButton> PortRadio = new List<RadioButton>();
             PortRadio.Add(radioButton5);
             PortRadio.Add(radioButton6);
             PortRadio.Add(radioButton7);
             PortRadio.Add(radioButton8);
```

On my code in 2 of the 4 of them (radioButton5 and radioButton6) I set:

```
///I am inside a for loop
 PortRadio[i].IsChecked = true;
 PortRadio[i].Content = "ACTIVE";
```

When I running The program the result is the following:

- Radiobutton 5 gets content "ACTIVE" and gets `"Checked"`
- Radiobutton 6 gets content "ACTIVE" and gets `"Checked"` but Radiobutton 5 gets Unchecked

This behaviour is like a have set the radiobuttons to a `listbox` with a `selectionmode` set to  `single` , but thats not the case and furthemore I dont know whats causing this behaviour and how to overcome it.

Comment: do all radio buttons have the same groupname?

Comment: I'm assuming all of these radio buttons have the same `name` attribute when printed to the html. By nature, only 1 radio button can be checked at a time. If you want multiple to be checked, you would need a checkbox.

Comment: Do you have to use RadioButtons?  Or can you switch to CheckBoxes in this case?

Comment: Thanks never thought of it..know I made silly Q from the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a `RadioButton` is that you can only select 1 in a group. If you want to be able to select multiple, use different group names for the buttons, or even better, use a `CheckBox` a checkbox is group independent.

Comment: Thanks never thought of it..know I made silly Q from the beginning